# Can't install drupal 7.24 using MAMP on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, drupal, drupal-7, mamp, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install drupal 7.24 using MAMP on OS X Mavericks.

I have installed drupal using MAMP hundreds of times before.

I am able to unpack the drupal core files into /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal.

I am able to pull up the install.php at localhost:8888/drupal/.

I create my database using the phpmyadmin with MAMP.

I go to install drupal, enter in my databse information with user:root and pass:root.

Here is where my issue comes in. The tables are created fine in the database, however, the install script loops back to the first step. I continue through again and it asks me to enter database information again. At which point, I do, and the same issue occurs. Randomly it will let me through to set up my site with a drupal error of "No active batch."

I have tested an install of drupal 7.24 on another server with no issues. The only thing different is that I have upgraded to OSX Mavericks. I have tried installing drupal using MAMP now on two different Macbook Pros running Mavericks and have had the same exact issue.

I have google'd this issue but can't seem to find similar issues. I will keep looking. If you have any ideas as to what would be causing the drupal install to fail, it would be much appreciated. Until then, I will use Acquia.

Thanks!

Comment: there may be a file written out that is not able to be written out due to permissions, you can check in the apache log, or check perms.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exact issue yesterday and couldn't figure this out for hours. Today I was able to successfully get past the loop back problem you describe above. I cannot say exactly what the root cause of this issue is but it seems to be a display/timing issue.

Once you enter in the database creds and click submit, the loop back to step one occurs. DO NOT re-enter the database creds here. At this point you can do one of the following:

- Wait for about 20 seconds and hit 'control' + 'R'
- Continuously hit 'control' + 'R' (refresh) until the page moves forward to the installation loader.

You will see the modules being installed. Then it will show you completed. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and I can confirm waiting a few seconds and reloading the page helps! Thanks for that!

Comment: I'm astonished this error still exists but can contest that refresh does work after you enter your db info once. Wait the 20secs then refresh. Modules will then load. Weird but works.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions above worked for me.  I waited for about 1 minute after I got stuck and pressed CMD + R to refresh the page.  The module installation process begun (saw the progress bar) and Drupal was successfully installed.